# Manage data coming from a textarea edited by users

Tags: textarea

I'm studying a solution to manage data coming from a textarea edited by users.
I'll have to give the chance to the users to add some basic HTML tags (links, bold, list and something else).
My big concern is about the security.
The data will be saved in a mySql db.

Any advice in order to avoid as much as possible security problems?
What is the best way to save this kind of text in a database ?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

The best way to solve this is to make a whitelist of the allowed tags. Through JavaScript you can warn the users that they are entering invalid data, but to secure your data at the server side you need to strip them out of the content. A script tag for example should be handled with care. If you want your users to enter those, and other users to be able to view it, some more complex handling is needed.

A neat solution is to escape all the white listed tags and to encode the other ones as characters, so that a `<script>` tag becomes `&lt;script&gt;`. That way, if you output it in your html it won't be seen as a valid tag but as characters placed after each other.

If you need a more specific solution for your own language please provide some more details, but this is sufficient as a global concept.

Comment: I was thinking about a whitelist of the allowed tags even cause I don't want to give users to many options (just basic tags like h3 h4 h5 bold list and something else). I'm going to use PHP. Do you think I can use some script ready to use? Any advice about the best way to save the data in the database?

Comment: Sorry, didn't get the notification somehow. I think it's no problem to use a predefined script, there are a lot out there you can use already. For saving the data in the database you shouldn't worry that much if you trust that script you're going to use. Make sure that only the tags you allow go in, and definitely escape all the characters with it!